# drupal 7 ubercart there are no products in your shopping cart for anonymous user

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

we are using drupal 7 ubercart module when anonymous user click on add to cart it shows there are no products in your shopping cart.

Recently we migrate our site and and import users table from another drupal i check that uid for anonymous uses is set to 0. and cleared session table.

i'm not using boost module.

i try to find solution fron https://www.drupal.org/node/679422 but it not help me out.

when uses refresh a page for 2 or 3 times then add to cart work for some time.

Please, anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.